# Create a chart with WHILE statement applying only for one column in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, database, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, graph

I would like to create a statistical chart for my database on ASP.NET website which I created beforehand. The data is in a boolean format - the output desired is calculate all the data in the table on Y axis and true values for X axis.

As I'm using the Design view I tried to use the build query but it just gives me the wrong results:

```
SELECT COUNT(Voting.Voting_ID) AS Expr1, 
       COUNT(Voting.Canvassed) AS Expr2 
       FROM (Voting 
       INNER JOIN Elector 
       ON Voting.Voting_ID = Elector.Voting_ID) 
       WHERE (Voting.Canvassed = 0)
```

Thats the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(Voting.Voting_ID) AS Expr1,
       COUNT(Voting.Canvassed) AS Expr2 
       FROM (Voting 
       INNER JOIN Elector 
       ON Voting.Voting_ID = Elector.Voting_ID) 
       WHERE (Voting.Canvassed = 0)
```

Result:
3264,3264

Where the result I am looking for it 4870,3264. (4870 is the whole amount of entries)

Source code:

```
              SelectCommand="SELECT COUNT(Voting.Canvassed) AS Expr2, COUNT(Voting.Canvassed) AS Expr1 FROM (Voting INNER JOIN Elector ON Voting.Voting_ID = Elector.Voting_ID) WHERE (Voting.Canvassed = 0)">
          </asp:AccessDataSource>
```

I tried changing the sql query in the script but it keeps giving me errors in terms of syntax. Any idea how this could be done?

Comment: Are you certain that your queries pull the correct data? I don't see ASP.NET having anything to do with this question when it's a SQL/data issue.

Comment: I'm using query builder and whenever i try to count only one of the selected rows it keeps saying that the query is incorrect. I have tried putting couple of separate select queries but it simply does not allow that for some reason.